# Realm - Why are notification blocks triggered when a write transaction begins?

Tags: ios, realm

I noticed today that Realm notification blocks are triggered when a write transaction begins. Intuitively I would have thought that *ending* a write transaction would trigger collection notifications with the changes that just happened, but I tracked down a crash in my code today resulting from a notification block being called when a write transaction begins.

Relevant stack frames before my notification handling is invoked:

```
    frame #17: 0x0000000102535b98 Realm`RLMNotificationToken* RLMAddNotificationBlock<realm::Results>(this=0x00000001742974f0, changes=0x000000016fdf9de0, err=<unavailable>) block_pointer, bool)::'lambda'(realm::CollectionChangeSet const&, std::exception_ptr)::operator()(realm::CollectionChangeSet const&, std::exception_ptr) const + 608 at RLMCollection.mm:345
    frame #18: 0x0000000102535700 Realm`realm::CollectionChangeCallback::Impl<RLMNotificationToken* RLMAddNotificationBlock<realm::Results>(objc_object*, realm::Results&, void (objc_object*, RLMCollectionChange*, NSError*) block_pointer, bool)::'lambda'(realm::CollectionChangeSet const&, std::exception_ptr)>::after(this=0x00000001742974e8, change=0x000000016fdf9de0) + 56 at collection_notifications.hpp:157
    frame #19: 0x000000010248723c Realm`realm::CollectionChangeCallback::after(this=0x000000016fdf9dd0, c=0x000000016fdf9de0) + 64 at collection_notifications.hpp:122
    frame #20: 0x0000000102487198 Realm`auto realm::_impl::CollectionNotifier::after_advance(this=0x000000016fdf9f90, lock=0x000000016fdf9ef0, callback=0x0000000103b62520)::$_9::operator()<std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>, realm::_impl::CollectionNotifier::Callback>(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, realm::_impl::CollectionNotifier::Callback&) const + 156 at collection_notifier.cpp:326
    frame #21: 0x0000000102479780 Realm`void realm::_impl::CollectionNotifier::for_each_callback<realm::_impl::CollectionNotifier::after_advance()::$_9>(this=0x00000001049d3e18, fn=0x000000016fdf9f90)::$_9&&) + 236 at collection_notifier.cpp:367
    frame #22: 0x0000000102479688 Realm`realm::_impl::CollectionNotifier::after_advance(this=0x00000001049d3e18) + 28 at collection_notifier.cpp:315
    frame #23: 0x000000010247ba3c Realm`realm::_impl::NotifierPackage::after_advance(this=0x000000016fdfa5e8) + 352 at collection_notifier.cpp:474
    frame #24: 0x00000001026c8de4 Realm`void (anonymous namespace)::advance_with_notifications<realm::_impl::transaction::begin(context=0x0000000174221480, sg=0x0000000104020200, func=0x000000016fdfa540, notifiers=0x000000016fdfa5e8)::$_1>(realm::BindingContext*, realm::SharedGroup&, realm::_impl::transaction::begin(realm::SharedGroup&, realm::BindingContext*, realm::_impl::NotifierPackage&)::$_1&&, realm::_impl::NotifierPackage&) + 1152 at transact_log_handler.cpp:674
    frame #25: 0x00000001026c8958 Realm`realm::_impl::transaction::begin(sg=0x0000000104020200, context=0x0000000174221480, notifiers=0x000000016fdfa5e8) + 56 at transact_log_handler.cpp:702
    frame #26: 0x00000001024de620 Realm`realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator::promote_to_write(this=0x0000000103b0e108, realm=0x0000000103b0e498) + 328 at realm_coordinator.cpp:741
    frame #27: 0x00000001026766b4 Realm`realm::Realm::begin_transaction(this=0x0000000103b0e498) + 552 at shared_realm.cpp:483
    frame #28: 0x000000010262df3c Realm`::-[RLMRealm beginWriteTransaction](self=0x00000001740a9fc0, _cmd="beginWriteTransaction") + 48 at RLMRealm.mm:437
```

In a particular use case in my code, one of my notification callbacks creates a new set of RLMResults to display in a table and adds a notification block to it. Adding the notification block raises the expected exception in that case: `Cannot create asynchronous query while in a write transaction`.

That rule is easy to understand, I'm really just curious about why beginning a write transaction would trigger collection notifications, instead of waiting until after the transaction.

Comment: Beginning a write transaction automatically bumps the Realm version to the latest on the thread you're starting the transaction on, therefore it makes sense for collections to be notified about a Realm version increase. I think this generally happens only if you execute write transactions on the UI thread, which is generally not good practice. (take this with a grain of salt, collection notifications aren't in on Android yet, so I could be wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a write was made on a different thread between when the Realm was last refreshed and when you begin a write transaction, beginning the write transaction will implicitly refresh the Realm first. If this results in anything changing, any applicable notifications will be sent immediately to notify you of the change.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the notifications are dispatched _inside_ of the write transaction, as opposed to before it begins? Your explanation definitely makes sense, but I'd still expect that to happen in a different order. 1) refresh, 2) dispatch notifications, 3) enter transaction, instead of 3, 1, 2.

Comment: Sending them outside the write transaction could result in another thread making a write while notifications are being sent. Ideally what would happen is that the thread would acquire the write lock, send notifications, and then begin the transaction, but that currently isn't possible due to implementation issues.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your responses! <3 Realm.